# Graph definition of the Helly property

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

This quote is found on page 33 of [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=FIM/19):

> A graph class defined by a geometric intersection model has the Helly property if for every clique $C$, there is some single point $p$ such that every vertex of $C$ includes the point $p$.

It is regarding graphs that are realized as intersections of geometric objects, e.g. interval graphs.

I don't understand how every vertex of a clique can include a point, i.e., how a point can include a point.

In reading other versions of Helly's property & Helly's theorem, I don't yet see how they align with this statement.

What does this quote mean?

Perhaps he is using "vertex" differently than I think, though I can't see it is defined anywhere in the chapter.

For context, it follows:

> Interval graphs have the Helly property; clearly, this means that the maximal clique problem is solvable efficiently given an intersection model, since we only need to check how many vertex intervals cover each endpoint of an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the graph is "defined by a geometric intersection model", a vertex of the graph corresponds to some subset of $\mathbb R^n$, with edges between intersecting subsets.

The Helly property says that for every clique $C$ in the graph, the vertices of that clique - that is, the subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ - all contain some common point of $\mathbb R^n$.

(If you have a bunch of vertices - subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ - that all contain a point $p \in \mathbb R^n$, then they form a clique, because any two of them intersect. The Helly property is a converse to that.)