# Helly property of interval graph implies low number of maximal cliques

Tags: graph-theory

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635512).

From [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=FIM/19), it defines:

> A graph class defined by a geometric intersection model has the Helly property if for every clique 
> , there is some single point 
> such that every vertex of 
> includes the point .

It goes on to say,

> Interval graphs have the Helly property; clearly, this means that the
> maximal clique problem is solvable efficiently given an intersection
> model, since we only need to check how many vertex intervals cover
> each endpoint of an interval. It's not hard to see that the Helly property implies that there are $O(n)$ maximal cliques in an interval graph.

The author claims this is clear and not hard to see, though I don't see it despite thinking about it for a while.

Let $G$ be an interval graph with $n$ vertices, then each vertex $v\in V(G)$ is identified with an interval.

Then a clique $C\subseteq V(G)$ is a set of intervals. Due to the Helly property, there exists a point $p$ such that every $v\in C$ (identified as an interval) includes $p$.

This is where it gets foggy for me following the argument.

How does this imply $O(n)$ maximal cliques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the point $p$ with the property that every vertex of a clique $C$ is an interval containing $p$, and start moving it left. As $p$ moves, every vertex of $C$ will still be an interval containing $p$, until a key moment: the moment when $p$ hits the leftmost endpoint of one of the intervals.

By doing this, we see that if our intervals are $\{[a_1, b_1], [a_2, b_2], \dots, [a_n,b_n]\}$, then every clique $C$ doesn't just have a point $p$ contained in every vertex: it has a point $p$ **equal to $a_i$ for some $i$** which is contained in every vertex.

We can also go the other way: for each endpoint $a_i$, find the clique $C$ of all intervals containing $a_i$. This gives us $n$ cliques $C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n$.

Because every clique $C$ has a point $a_i$ contained in every vertex of $C$, and clique $C_i$ consists of *all* vertices containing $a_i$, every clique $C$ is contained in $C_i$ for some $i$. Therefore the $n$ cliques $C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n$ include all maximal cliques of the graph.